# Text attribute of an asp label using JavaScript is not staying changed

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have a button:

```
<asp:Button Text="Reset" runat="server" ID="ResetButton" OnClientClick="ResetClick()"/>
```

that runs the following JavaScript function when it gets clicked:

```
function ResetClick() {
    document.getElementById("<%=lblError.ClientId%>").innerHTML = "";
}
```

That changes the text on this label:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" Style="color: Red;" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

Unfortunately, my code behind also changes the label text to an error message using the following code:

```
lblError.Text = "No data is available"
```

When I click the reset button, the text is momentarily cleared and then it fills again with the error message. Is there any way to have the code behind set a message in the label and let the JavaScript clear the message?

Comment: Do you want to post back every time you click that button? If not then add `return false;` in the onclientclick.

Comment: I added the return false; to the function and updated the question to reflect the change. This still did nothing to fix the problem.

Comment: Nevermind, I misunderstood what you said. I added return false; inside the attribute and that fixed my problem. Mind posting that as an answer so I can give you credit for answering my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want the button to post back then you should add `return false;` to the OnClientClick attribute:

```
<asp:Button Text="Reset" runat="server" ID="ResetButton" OnClientClick="ResetClick(); return false;"/>
```

PS: adding as an answer since it sounds like it was helpful.